# Redirect one page to another

Tags: angularjs

I have some problem to redirect one page to another
i used code in controller

```
 $window.location.href = '/test';
 $location.path( "/test");
```

but when i used it, it will redirect on home page

```
 .state('test', {
    url: '/tests/:testId',
    templateUrl: TEMPLATE_URL + 'tests/test.html',
    controller: "testController",
    resolve: {
      testId: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
          return $stateParams.testId;
        }]
    },
    data: {
      title: "Test"
    }
  });
```

I want to redirect on above page. 
I have create a function in controller and call on the click of table row. but when i click on row this redirect to my home page.

Comment: where is the state for /path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one state, called `test` with URL `/test/:testId`. Since you are obviously using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/), which works with states, executing the following code should do the trick:

```
$state.go('test', {'testId': 123});
```

Don't forget to inject `$state` into your controller for that.

If you want to use the kind of "hard-coded" URL-redirect (`$location.path` and `$window.location.href` are direct-URL-redirects) the code would look like this:

```
$window.location.href = '/test/123';
$location.path( "/test/123");
```

You forgot the parameters in your example.

Comment: This is not work i used it $state.go('test', {'testId': 123}); but it also redirect home page.

Comment: @VipinJain then please post the full code of your controller to your question.

Comment: ok i am trying to do this.i can't post the actual code. but if i cant i will definetly send.

Comment: @VipinJain The `$state.go` or the other one?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to use :

```
$state.go('test', { testId : 'yourTestId' }, {reload: true});
```

or

```
$state.go('test'); //For a route without params
```

Sure you have to inject $state in your controller .

If you want to use

```
$window.location.href = '/plan';
$location.path( "/plan");
```

You have to configure your web server to accepte this :

Exemple with nginx :

```
location / {
               ##try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html$args =404;
               try_files $uri $uri/  /index.html =404;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use `$state.go()`

```
$state.go('test', {'testId': 123});
```

Click here for more information about it http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state